# How to deploy application to minikube use registry in Kubernetes?

Tags: http, https, kubernetes, docker-registry, minikube

Intalled registry in Kubernetes `kubectl create -f kube-registry.yaml`.

There has docker image in it:

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["app1"]}
```

Also did port-forward:

```
kubectl port-forward --namespace kube-system \
$(kubectl get po -n kube-system | grep kube-registry-v0 | \
awk '{print $1;}') 5000:5000
```

Set `image: 192.168.99.100:5000/app1` in Kubernetes deployment file(`deployment.yaml`).

After deploy it to cluster:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

Check status from Kubernetes dashboard on `Deployments` menu, got error:

```
Failed to pull image "192.168.99.100:5000/app1": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://192.168.99.100:5000/v1/_ping: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"}
Error syncing pod
```

The reason is can't get registry content from http protocol. How to resolve it?

---

Added `insecure-registries` by (The real content is `192.168.99.100:5000`. Here is a different IP/port picture.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Configure docker to pull image using http `insecure-registries`

create this file in your node and restart docker process, then try to deploy

`/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["192.168.99.100:5000"]
}
```

Comment: I set the `insecure-registries` from Mac docker app as I added a picture above. That still not work.

Comment: looks at the error message, its trying to pull the image from this ip `192.168.99.100:5000` you image shows different ip

Answer (score 4):

## Useful resource

```
minikube start --insecure-registry "10.0.0.0/24"
```

> https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/insecure_registry.md